# Set theory - Optimization

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a school there are 100 students in each of the classes from 5th class tot 10th class.  The number of students who passed in four subjects - Mathematics, Science, English and Social Studies - in each class is given below.

[image]

**Question:-** What is the maximum number of students who passed in at least 2 subjects in 5th class ?

**My attempt :-**

There would be 5 types of students possible amongst the 100 in class 5th or for that matter in any class

1. People who passed in exactly 1 subject (let's call it a)
2. People who passed in exactly 2 subjects (let's call it b)
3. People who passed in exactly 3 subjects (let's call it c)
4. People who passed in all the 4 subjects (let's call it d)
5. People who passed in none of the subjects (let's call it e)

$a+b+c+d+e=100---(1)$

ATQ, I need to maximize $b+c+d$

One more equation which I can form is :-

$a+2b+3c+4d=82+88+78+92$

$a+2b+3c+4d=340---(2)$

Now how shall I proceed to maximize $b+c+d$ using the following equations ?

Comment: Do you have the answer? And is it, by any chance, $100$?

Comment: **(1)** Question is over-specified. Why we need Data about other Classes ? **(2)** Your way may work , but it is too long. **(3)** We know the Class has 100 Students , hence max can not be more than that. Can max be 100 ? Draw Venn Diagram for 2 Subjects , try to get the Common Part. Do that for the other 2 Subjects , getting the Common Part. We can then Conclude that 100 is Possible.

Answer (score 1):

This method avoids the equations and focuses on how to *find* a case such that the max value is $100$ and does not attempt to *prove* that such a case exists (although one case is sufficient). The maximum possible value is $100$. Throughout this answer: M- Math, S- Science, E- English, SS- Social studies. One such possible configuration is

```
M E SS S - 50
M   SS S - 16
  E SS S - 14
M E SS   - 6
M   SS   - 6
M E    S - 4
  E    S - 4
```

Suppose every student passes in $2$ subjects. Then there would be $200$ passes, but there are $340$, so $100$ students may pass in at least $2$ subjects.
Here is an approach to finding such examples:

- First, divide the $100$ students into $4$ groups, and each group will pass in exactly $2$ subjects. One such configuration:

```
M      S - 25
M   SS   - 25
  E    S - 25
  E SS   - 25
```

- Now, notice that adding a subject to any group will not affect the other subjects. $50$ students pass in Math, so, we need more $32$ students. We can split the $25$ into two groups, and add $M$ in only one group. This won't affect the other subjects too. Split in such a way that we get the proper number of students. For example, we can increase the number of students who passed math by :

```
M      S - 25
M   SS   - 25
  E    S - 25 ------>   E    S - 10
                |
                ----> M E    S - 15
  E SS   - 25 ------>   E SS   - 8
                |
                ----> M E SS   - 17
```

- Do this for the other subjects until you arrive at a solution (maybe not the same as the one above).

---

A rigorous proof can be constructed using this algorithm. First, we describe the algorithm, then show that splitting the groups does not change the number, then adding a subject in a group does not affect other subjects, and finally: Since in every subject, more than $50$ and less than $100$ students passed, for a given subject, we can always split some group(s) and add that subject in few of the new groups so that the no. of students who passed that subject are equal to the required number.